# Knockout validation: Dynamic constraints

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, durandal, knockout-validation

I'm using Durandal, which in turn leverages off of Knockout.

I want to be able to **Change validation lengths dynamically**

[image]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rohan_buchner/AydYG/)

The fiddle seems to be behaving slightly different than my "working" solution, but its still not doing what I'm wanting/expecting it to.

**Viewmodel JS:**

**[Attempt 1]**

```
define(function () {

   var self = this;

   self.userInfo = {       
        IdOrPassportNumber: ko.observable().extend({
            required: true,
            pattern: {
                message: 'A message',
                params: /some regex/
            }
        }),
        IdType: ko.observable()
    },

    self.isIdValid = ko.validatedObservable({ 
         IdOrPassportNumber: self.userInfo.IdOrPassportNumber 
    });

    self.userInfo.IdOrPassportNumber.subscribe(function (value) {
          if (isIdValid.isValid()) {
               console.log('YOLO!');
          }
    });

    self.userInfo.IdType.subscribe(function (value) {
        console.log(value);
        if (value === 'Passport') {
            self.userInfo.IdOrPassportNumber.extend({ maxLength: 15 });
        } else {
            self.userInfo.IdOrPassportNumber.extend({ maxLength: 13 });
        }
    });    

    var viewModel = {
        userInfo: self.userInfo
    };

    viewModel["errors"] = ko.validation.group(viewModel.userInfo);
    viewModel["errors"].showAllMessages();

    return viewModel;
});
```

What seems to be happening is that when i start typing i get the max & min validation of 13, but if i continue typing the validation changes to 15. I have tried another route of, setting the  min & max length in the initial observable extend EG, just after the regex, and then setting the min and max length to use an observable, to no success.

**[Attempt 2]**

```
   self.userInfo = {       
       IdOrPassportNumber: ko.observable().extend({               
            maxLength: self.maxLength(), 
            minlength: self.maxLength()
       }),
       IdType: ko.observable()
   },

   self.maxLength = ko.observable();

   self.userInfo.IdType.subscribe(function (value) {

          if (value === 'Passport') {
             self.maxLength(15)
          } else {
              self.maxLength(3)
          }
    });
```

Comment: Can you use http://cdnjs.com/ to grab the knockout validation plugin...

Comment: Done. +1 Ps very cool site. Bookmarked for sure :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were so close :-)
You must provide the observable itself, not the unwrapped value. So just remove the `()` from `maxLength()` - the validation library will automatically unwrap it for you.

```
self.userInfo = {       
   IdOrPassportNumber: ko.observable().extend({               
        maxLength: self.maxLength, 
        minlength: self.maxLength
   }),
   IdType: ko.observable()
},
```

Here's another example with dynamic regex patterns.

```
    zipPostalPattern = ko.pureComputed(() => this.countryCode() === 'US' ? '^\\d{5}(?:[-\\s]\\d{4})?$' : '');
    zipOrPostal: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable('').extend(
    {
        required: true,
        pattern: {
            message: 'This is not a valid postcode for the country',
            params: this.zipPostalPattern
        }
    });
```

or (if you don't want a message).

```
    zipPostalPattern = ko.pureComputed(function() { return this.countryCode() === 'US' ? '^\\d{5}(?:[-\\s]\\d{4})?$' : ''});
    zipOrPostal: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable('').extend(
    {
        required: true,
        pattern:  self.zipPostalPattern
    });
```

**Important**: If you don't want a custom message don't just remove the `message` parameter and leave `pattern = { params: this.zipPostalPattern }` because it won't work. If you don't have a message you must set the Regex/string directly for the `pattern` parameter.

Or of course you can just define the computed observable in place (here it's ok to call `countryCode()` as a function because that's how computed's work)

```
    zipOrPostal: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable('').extend(
    {
        required: true,
        pattern:  ko.pureComputed(function() { 
                     return self.countryCode() === 'US' ? '^\\d{5}(?:[-\\s]\\d{4})?$' : ''
                  })
    });
```

Comment: For anyone else reading this. I'm unable to test this against this exact situation I had at this at that stage, (no longer on this project). I do prefer @Simon_Weaver's solution as the accepted solution, and will mark it as such.

Comment: Thanks. I have to say it only occured to me today that I might be able to pass an observable as a parameter to a rule, and I got very excited - then realized perhaps it might not work - but then I got excited again that it seems to work very well :-) From what I remember it isn't clearly documented, but it's very easy if you already know how to use Knockout and adds some great flexibility.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

I made use of the [custom validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) feature, more specifically the
 [single use custom validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Custom-Validation-Rules) as this wont be re-used elsewhere.

**[Attempt 3]**

```
    self.userInfo = {    
        IdOrPassportNumber: ko.observable().extend({
            required: true,
            pattern: {
                message: 'A message',
                params: /some regex/
            },
            validation: {
               validator: function (val) {
                   if (self.userInfo.IdType() === 'Id') { 
                      return val.length === 13; 
                   } else { 
                      return val.length === 15; 
                   }
                },
               message: function () {
                  if (self.userInfo.IdType() === 'Id') {
                    return 'Required: 13 characters';
                  } else {
                    return 'Required: 15 characters';
                  }
               }
            }
        })
     }
```

Comment: As a side note. I noticed that the order of the validations also matter, so say you want your custom validator (or any other) for that matter to trigger first, order them accordingly

Comment: Isn't it better to use two different fields with fixed validation and change binding on the page `<input type="text" data-bind="value: idType()==='Id' ? id : password" />`? On save just write `var idOrPassword=id()||password()`.

Answer (score 4):

consider this

```
self.iDNumber = ko.observable('').extend({
        required: {
            params: true,
            message: 'ID Number is a required field.',
            insertMessages: false
        },
        SouthAfricanIDNumber: {
            message: 'Please enter a valid South African ID number.',
            onlyIf: function() {
                return self.identityType() === 'SAID';
            }
        }
    });
```

where SouthAfricanIDNumber is a custom validation that uses regex.

Comment: welcome to SO :), but see my accepted answer. (i'm no longer on the project. but i'll keep it in mind for the future)

Comment: +1 to encourage `spacerogue` with his/her first post.