# How to add multiple messages for validation based on the condition knockout js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have two error messages but only one is shown based on `vendor` value. The initial value for `vendor` as application starts is null. After that, based on the user input the `vendor` value is changed. However, the validation error message says "Input is required" regardless of `vendor` value - even the condition is met. It seems to me that the value for `self.agreement` is not updated.

I have looked at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313776/knockout-validation-dynamic-constraints) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42511581/conditional-validation-in-knockout) , and applied the techniques but none of them worked for me.

**index.js**

```
 self.agreement = (vendor == "BAS")? ko.observable().extend({
      required:{message:"Should be 9 digit "},
      pattern:{
        params:/^\d{9}$/
      }
    }):ko.observable().extend({ required:{message:"Input is required", onlyIf:function(){return !self.sample()}} });
```

**index.cshtml**

```
<input data-bind="init, value: agreement" class="form-control" type="text" value="@(Model.Ani)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're re-scoping the observable.

```
ko.observable().extend({}):ko.observable().extend({})
```

Try it like this instead

```
ko.observable().extend({}).extend({}).extend({})......
```

Here's a sample.

```
Price: local.Price.extend({ required: true }).extend({ number: true }).extend({ pattern: '(\$\s*)?(([1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?|0?\.\d*[1-9]\d*)' })
```